# Crashing .svg in Nautilus

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, svg

It happens sometimes, but I've managed to restore the Nautilus without rebooting the system.But today, when I attached a file `.svg` by e-mail, he first caught the Google Chrome and then Firefox 5, and when I open the folder in Nautilus Ubuntu crashed. Making me to restart the PC via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

I know there is a bug related to it, and I also know that there is no preview thumbnails for Nautilus, but that could be set up so only thumbnails of files `.svg` did not appear?

Comment: you mention that there is a Launchpad bug related to this issue you are having. Mind posting a link to it here?

Answer (score 1):

Open the svg up in Evince, it should cause librsvg to crash in the same way. It should also crash Eye of Gnome too. You can turn off thumbnailing in the nautilus settings, but the preview images are still generated when you click on certain media types.

Gnome isn't known for being very configurable or modular, you're only hope is to install a fixed version of librsvg or fix the svg files to remove the issue.